# How to prevent work from exacerbating situational depression?

Tags: phd, research-process, health, emotional-responses

I am experiencing situational depression. This isn't 'discouragement' due to research. Me feeling inadequate in my research is NOT the problem. The problem is that the steps involved in research seem to be at best, not helping, or worse - exacerbating the negative emotions that are associated with depression.

Let me rephrase that - I have not felt 'impostor syndrome', and I do not feel it now (sorry if it sounds a tad bigheaded but I want to avoid confusion).

I have some idea of the things I need to do to combat depression, but it seems to me that they all involve staying away from work at the lab. Has anyone faced this? Can I do anything to prevent loss of productivity?

Usually, I hear the following ways to fight depression:

1. Get in a routine.
2. Set goals.
3. Do something new (don't get stuck in a rut)

Now, these can be applied when I am free. But the majority of my waking hours are in the lab (or supposed to be). While doing bio research:

1. The routine/ schedule is thrown off whack by unforeseen developments/ etc.
2. Goals, even minor ones, may or may not be reached. This is research.
3. Can't help getting stuck in a rut if we're trying to get data out of a particular experiment.

I took a week off, and it helped, but doesn't seem to have helped enough. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused about whether you are looking for (1) ways to remain productive despite having depleted emotional and mental energy, or (2) ways to prevent your work from exacerbating the depression. In other words, are you trying to "fix" your work productivity, given your depression? Or are you trying to "fix" your depression, given the requirement of having to remain productive at work? Can you clarify?

Comment: Both, but more (2) than (1). The responses to the question you linked are mostly in the vein of 'Don't worry - research is tough. We all are in the same boat'. I understand that. Or, let me put it this way - I have never felt a sense of impostor syndrome, and neither do I do so now. I simply cannot seem to work as I did before. In fact, the work seems to be becoming part of the problem, although I see no reason for it to be. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: I agree with OP that the linked question does not seem to apply at all to this situation. I also agree that this is a style of questions that seems familiar, so it may be a duplicate. But it is certainly NOT a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: OK. I edited to clarify. I also encourage you to read: [Strategies to avoid burn out due to systemic lack of time](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/81724/), [Is it common for people in academia to experience prolonged lack of sleep and how to deal with it?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/41856/), [What can I do to recover from a short term burnout?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7668/), (to be continued...)

Comment: [How to prevent physical/psychological health side effects of workaholism in academia and research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/26779/), [Overcoming depression and getting back on rails with PhD work](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28257/) and of course [How should I deal with discouragement as a graduate student?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2219/). (Read _all_ the answers, not just the top one on each post.)  Even if not identical to your situation, I imagine most of the answers that can possibly be applied to yours, are mentioned among those.

Comment: In particular: note that many of those answers include specific, concrete steps you can take. Not just commiseration.

Answer (score 4):

You are mistakenly conflating hours spent in the lab with productivity. There is certainly a point of "diminished returns," where extra hours don't actually improve your productivity, and actively harms it in the longer run.

A few ways to change up your routine:

- Work on your most important task first thing in the morning.
- Focus exclusively on your work for 20-30 minutes at a time. This means no checking email, no chatting with lab mates, or other distractions. After you're done with your block of time, take a few minutes to recharge before restarting (or moving to a new task).
- Avoid obsessively checking your email. Pick a few times per day to answer your email and engage in social media, and stick to it. (And don't spend multiple hours during such sessions; figure out what's important and what isn't, so that you can be finished in 15-20 minutes or so.)

You'll find you probably get more done in less time following such an approach than just spending tons of hours in the laboratory. This will also give you time for your personal life, which brings me to my other point:

> "Block out" time in your schedule for "recharging" activities.

The nature of the "recharging" activity will depend on what works best for you: some people exercise, others engage in artistic or creative activities, and still others meditate. It doesn't really matter what you do to clear your mind and "recharge your batteries"; however, you should make time for it, and make sure that you stick to it. It doesn't need to be an extensive commitment: even an hour or two per week can suffice.